# Will updating a uniform value stall the whole rendering pipeline?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

The [glBufferSubData manpage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBufferSubData.xml)'s notes section contains the following paragraph:

> Consider using multiple buffer objects to avoid stalling the rendering pipeline during data store updates. If any rendering in the pipeline makes reference to data in the buffer object being updated by glBufferSubData, especially from the specific region being updated, that rendering must drain from the pipeline before the data store can be updated.

While the [glUniform* manpage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glUniform.xml) doesn't mention the pipeline at all.
However, I would have thought that uniforms are just as important as buffers, given that they're supposed to be uniform across all shader invocations.
So, if I perform a draw call, change a uniform value and then perform another draw call on the same shader, will both draw calls run concurrently with different uniform values, or will the second draw call have to wait until *every* stage (vert/geom/frag) is complete on the first one?

Comment: I'm just speculating but it's a buffer like any other (I think), so obviously it will be locked in this way as it's part of the state to be rendered.  Nicol might know more about this, because it sounds kind-of driver determined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question in its general form is pretty much unanswerable. However consider this:

Since the advent of GLSL, and ARB's assembly language before that, uniform/parameter state has always been stored in the shader object. Only since uniform blocks and buffer objects has it been possible to separate uniform state from programs. So until that point, a good 5+ years, the only way to change a uniform was to change it in the program.

This means that pretty much every program that uses GLSL uses it in the standard way: bind a program, change uniforms, render, change uniforms, render, etc.

Now, imagine if doing this simple and obvious thing which hundreds of OpenGL programs did induced a *full pipeline stall*.

Driver developers are not stupid; even Intel's driver developers aren't that stupid. Whatever their hardware looks like, they can find a way to make uniform changes not induce a pipeline stall.